# Not All Code Paths return a value or await warning in C# mobile app

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, xamarin

I am building a Xamarin based app with an AWS back-end, based on [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-net-samples/tree/master/XamarinSamples/DynamoDB) sample. However, the following code from `app.cs` throws a warning:

> Async block lacks 'await' operator so code will run synchronously

```
public async Task storeToken()
{
    //Writes a New Token upon authentication in the directory
    DependencyService.Get<ISaveAndLoad>().SaveText("token", Token);
    StoredToken = DependencyService.Get<Gas_Sense.App.ISaveAndLoad> ().LoadText ("token");
}
```

However, if the `async` is removed from the function, I get this Error:

> `My_App.App.storeToken()': not all code paths return a value (CS0161)

Is there a way to fix these issues, or is it an issue with the compiler?

Comment: It looks like you are just starting with Task Parallel Library (TPL). Please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx so in the future you can avoid hard to track down bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async Task` is the asynchronous variant of `void`. If you remove the `async`, change `Task` to `void` (or return a `Task`)...